# Parsing response from llama2

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, llm

I want to extract phone numbers from a given text and i am prompting a llama2 model for that ..I want the output in form of a list but i am getting unnecessary output like sure here are the phone numbers etc etc...can anyone help how to only extract the phone numbers from the response?